# Are exceptions thrown reliably when using Ado.Net stored procedures?

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, ado.net, exception

If I try and call a stored procedure and there is a database error, will that raise as an exception in my C# code? Or do I need to check the result of the stored procedure and raise an exception myself?

Eg:

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("prc_InsertSomething", conn))
{
    if (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() != 1) // should I be doing this bit or not?
    {
        throw new DataException("Could not insert something");
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `ExecuteNonQuery`, you will *generally* be OK as long as the severity is high enough; however, be careful if you are **reading** data; for example, if you have a stored procedure that returns multiple grids and throws an exception (for example) just before the penultimate result-set, then **if** you don't iterate over the data you may never see the error.

This is because the error is injected into the TDS stream (not out-of-band). You need to consume the TDS *at least as far as the error* for your code to become aware of it.

Something as simple as (in the case of `IDataReader`):

```
while (reader.NextResult()) { }
```

after your consuming code will ensure you consume the entire inbound TDS stream.

Answer (score 2):

I really depends on the severity of the errror. Check out the following link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177497.aspx

> A RAISERROR severity of 11 to 19
>   executed in the TRY block of a
>   TRY…CATCH construct causes control to
>   transfer to the associated CATCH
>   block.
>
> Specify a severity of 10 or lower to
>   return messages using RAISERROR
>   without invoking a CATCH block. PRINT
>   does not transfer control to a CATCH
>   block.

So it will depend on the severity of the error that is thrown by your stored procedure whether or not it caught in the exception handler of the calling code.

Comment: I believe the OP is asking about intercepting the exception in the calling application, not the stored procedure itself.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the error, but normally, if a stored procedure fails it will cause a [`SqlException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlexception.aspx) to be thrown.

If you are not catching the error/exception in the stored procedure itself, it will bubble out through the database provider.